# Why does class inheritance and interface implementation involve objects?

Tags: class, object, oop, design-patterns, interface

> It's also important to understand the difference between class
> inheritance and interface inheritance (or subtyping). Class
> inheritance defines an object's implementation in terms of another
> object's implementation. In short, it's a mechanism for code and
> representation sharing. In contrast, interface inheritance (or
> subtyping) describes when an object can be used in place of
> another.
> It's easy to confuse these two concepts, because many languages don't make the distinction
> explicit. In languages like C++ and Eiffel, inheritance means both interface
> and implementation inheritance. The standard way to inherit an interface in C++ is
> to inherit publicly from a class that has (pure) virtual member functions. Pure interface
> inheritance can be approximated in C++ by inheriting publicly from pure abstract
> classes. Pure implementation or class inheritance can be approximated with private
> inheritance. In Smalltalk, inheritance means just implementation inheritance. You can
> assign instances of any class to a variable as long as those instances support the operation
> performed on the value of the variable.
> <sub>---《Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented
> Software 1st Edition》</sub>

1. Inheritance, isn't it simply about subclasses 'inheriting' properties and methods from the parent class. **How does it become 'an object's implementation in terms of another object's implementation'?** *When I implement class B inheriting from class A in my code, I don't instantiate any objects at all!*
2. Isn't an interface just a special kind of abstract class? (In comparison to abstract classes, interfaces only declare methods and don't declare properties or fields.) When a concrete class implements an interface, isn't it simply a class inheriting the 'interface' and implementing the methods declared in the interface? **How does this turn into 'an object can be used in place of another'?** *When I make class B implement interface A in my code, I don't instantiate any objects at all!*

Comment: "*I don't instantiate any objects*" is irrelevant. Your program will eventually instantiate and use such objects, otherwise you wouldn't be defining a class for them. The object is the goal, the class definition is just a means to describe its behaviour. Re 1: "another objects implementation" means "the implementation (of the method) that another object would use". Re 2: No, an interface is not just an abstract class. An interface here (in particular with respect to "subtyping") is a [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) in a [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

Answer (score 1):

Terminology evolves over time; nowadays you hear "interface" and think of the `interface` feature of languages like Java, C++, and Go, but when *Design Patterns* came out in 1994, none of those languages existed yet. So when it talks about "interface inheritance", that's not what it's referring to.

Rather, by "interface", it means the set of functionality that the class exposes to its clients. As applied to Java, that typically means its public methods — their names, signatures, and contracts — even methods that aren't specified by any "interface" in the Java sense.

In languages like Java, *all* inheritance is "interface inheritance"; if class A extends class B, then it automatically implements the interface of class B. (Well, there are some borderline cases — for example, [the Javadoc for java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) says that although it extends java.util.Date, we should pretend that it doesn't, because it doesn't behave 100% correctly as a java.util.Date — but at least as far as the Java language itself is concerned, all inheritance is interface inheritance and some classes just have bugs. ;-)   ) But that's not true of some languages; for example, C++ lets class A inherit from class B in a "private" way, where class A has all of class B's methods but they're all `private`, so clients can't call them. In that kind of inheritance, the *implementation* is inherited, but the *interface* is not. This is why *Design Patterns* draws this distinction.

Comment: So, what the book refers to as "class inheritance" is actually "Implementation inheritance"?

Comment: @bokabokaboka: Yes. I'm actually not sure exactly why it uses the term "class inheritance"; "classes" were basically the same thing back then (in Simula, Smalltalk, C++, etc.) as they are now, and C++ even had abstract classes, so it doesn't seem like "class inheritance" is a very precise way to refer to implementation inheritance as opposed to interface inheritance. But that's certainly what it means by it.

Comment: Can I understand it this way:   classes inheritance mentioned in the book refers to inheriting abstract classes (which contain both data and method declarations), while interface inheritance refers to inheriting interfaces (which contain only method declarations and no data items)? Here, data items refer to properties.

Comment: @bokabokaboka: Sorry, I'm not sure where you're getting that from; "class inheritance" doesn't have anything to do with abstract classes. "Class inheritance" is, roughly, when a subclass inherits an *implementation* (which it may or may not expose to its clients), whereas "interface inheritance" is when a subclass inherits a method *specification* (which it may provide its own implementation for). In C#, you have "class inheritance" whenever one class inherits from another (and arguably whenever it implements an interface with a default method), and *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* you have "interface inheritance" whenever one class inherits from another *or* whenever a class or struct implements an interface. Note that in C#, it's possible to have interface inheritance without class inheritance, but it's *not* possible to have class interface without interface inheritance. But in some languages, such as C++, it *is* possible to have class interface without interface inheritance; that is, C++ lets class A inherit from class B without actually exposing class B's functionality to clients.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it become 'an object's implementation in terms of another object's implementation'? When I implement class B inheriting from class A in my code, I don't instantiate any objects at all!

Let me show an example via C#:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public virtual string WhoIAm() 
    {
        return "I am an animal"; // Class inheritance defines an object's 
                                 // implementation in terms of
                                 // another object's implementation. 
    }
}


public class Cow : Animal
{

}
```

And let's run the above code:

```
Animal cow = new Cow();
cow.WhoIAm(); // "I am an animal" - this is an example of class inheritance 
              // defines an object's implementation in terms of
              // another object's implementation.
```

However, you can override a little bit behaviour without violation of [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

```
public class Cow : Animal
{
    public override string WhoIAm()
    {
        return "I am a cow!:)";
    }
}
```

> How does this turn into 'an object can be used in place of another'?

An interface is just similar to description of how object should look like. For example, cow usually has four legs and it says "Mooo". So let's create this description or interface:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string WhoIAm();
}
```

And then we will create concrete implementations of the above description:

```
public class Cow : IAnimal
{
    public string WhoIAm()
    {
        return "I am a cow!:)";
    }
}

public class Pig : IAnimal
{
    public string WhoIAm()
    {
        return "I am a pig!:)";
    }
}
```

And then you can use any concrete implementations of this descrpition or interface. It can be done like this:

```
IAnimal animal = new Cow();
animal.WhoIAm(); // "I am a cow!:)"

animal = new Pig();
animal.WhoIAm(); // "I am a pig!:)"
```