# Regarding 'Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse;' Is my understanding correct?

Tags: c++, oop, interface, polymorphism

Shape is an interface.Shape declares a pure virtual function GetArea. GetArea is implemented in Ellipse and Rectangle respectively

```
//code1
Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse; 
ps2->GetArea();
```

1. Can code1 be considered an instance of an interface?
2. The code1 has the same effect as the code2

---

```
//code2    
 Ellipse* ps2 = new Ellipse;  
 ps2->GetArea();
```

The only advantage of code1 over code2 is that when executing the following code, you can directly pass a pointer of type 'Shape' to the function 'fun,' achieving polymorphism. This way, one 'fun' function can be compatible with two different types of pointers as input parameters

```
   void fun(Shape* ps){
   ps->GetArea();
   )
```

---

---

I haven't studied C++ systematically. I am learning C++ to understand this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77294999/13828038).Because I learned object-oriented programming through MATLAB, I am having difficulty understanding the difference between interface inheritance and class inheritance.
However, after a brief study of object-oriented programming concepts in C++, I realized that there is indeed a significant difference between interface inheritance and class inheritance in C++. Simply put, in C++, achieving polymorphism requires the use of virtual functions. Once you define a virtual function or a pure virtual function in the base class, you have an abstract class or interface (when all functions in the base class are pure virtual, you have an interface). However, in MATLAB, achieving polymorphism does not necessarily rely on virtual functions. I suspect MATLAB might have something similar to C++'s virtual function table for each method in a class. Therefore, there's no need to explicitly define virtual functions.
Similarly, in the book 《Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software 1st Edition》， the authors suggest 'Programming to an Interface, not an Implementation.' This advice reminded me of the code I often see in my C++ book, such as 'Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse;' I guess this kind of code might illustrate 'Programming to an Interface.' There are no similar statements in MATLAB. I can't understand why one would use

```
Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse;
```

instead of

```
Ellipse* ps2 = new Ellipse;
```

Perhaps it is to achieve 'Programming to an Interface, not an Implementation.'?

But, as Paul McKenzie mentioned in the comments, 'You can pass an Ellipse* to fun,' it seems the reason for using 'Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse;' becomes less convincing. Someone told me that 'Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse;' restricts ps2 to only use methods declared in Shape. If you define 'Ellipse* ps2 = new Ellipse;' then ps2 can use methods defined in Ellipse even if they were not declared in Shape. However, I find this reason insufficient because Ellipse could simply use 'protected' to restrict certain methods from being accessed by objects

After reading the comments, I have two new questions.

1. Why do we often see statements like 'Shape* ps2 = new Ellipse;'?
   What is the main purpose of doing this?
2. Why follow the principle 'Programming to an Interface, not an Implementation'? What exactly does 'Programming to an
   Interface'mean?

Comment: *you can directly pass a pointer of type 'Shape'* -- You can do the same with code2.  You can pass an `Ellipse*` to `fun`.

Comment: Also, your usage of the term `interface` sounds like you are attempting to understand C++ by using another computer language.  The term `interface` is not used widely in C++ when describing classes, base classes, and abstract base classes.

Comment: "Can code1 be considered an instance of an interface?" the interface is the definition of `Shape`. In the code you are only using it. Whether `Shape` is just an interface or more is not clear from the code, we can only see that it is possible to convert a pointer to an `Ellipse` to a pointer to a `Shape` (and afaik this does imply that `Ellipse` inherits from `Shape`, but not sure if this is the only way, C++ has its ways...)

Comment: And you don't even have to use pointers and `new` to be polymorphic. `Ellipse ell; fun(&ell);` also works. C++ is a separate language!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your comment. I have added some content to the question to address your comment

Comment: "there is indeed a significant difference between interface inheritance and class inheritance in C++" -- no, not really. C++ does not provide a distinct interface feature, it only has classes. Note that a fundamental aspect of OOP is the concept of an interface, but that does not directly map to a C++ class.

Comment: BTW: One phrase you quoted has raised quite a few questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Programming+to+an+Interface%2C+not+an+Implementation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  Yes, C++ doesn't have explicit interfaces like C#. However, when all functions in a C++ class are pure virtual functions, can this class be considered as an interface?

Comment: Yes, you could. However, even a single, non-pure, virtual function effectively defines an interface. If you just say interface, it doesn't map to a specific C++ construct, so it may not be precise enough. Also, in C++, there is compile-time and run-time polymorphism. The former uses `template` and the latter `virtual`.